# Пересечение и объединение двух выпуклых многоугольников

Tags: c#, c++, математика

Как найти пересечение и объединение двух выпуклых многоугольников?
Многоугольники задаются координатами вершин в порядке обхода по контуру.

Comment: Есть готовое решение в виде библиотеки: [здесь](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~toby/alan/software). Также советую почитать [данную работу](http://www.inf.tsu.ru/library/Publications/2002/54.pdf).

Comment: _GPC is no longer hosted by The University of Manchester. Other hosting arrangements are being considered._ - вот поэтому ответы ссылки и не приветствуются

Answer (score 5):

Точки пересечения выпуклых многоугольников эффективно ищутся алгоритмом O'Rourke - из его книги "Computational Geometry in C", книгу найти нетрудно, [исходники на сайте](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/books/ftp.html) доступны (*convconv*).

Имея точки и зная, на каких ребрах происходит пересечение, можно построить пересечение (всегда выпуклый) и объединение (может быть невыпуклым)

Есть ещё библиотека [Clipper](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php) c реализацией  на нескольких языках и биндингами ещё к нескольким.